# Does Google Nexus 4 work in India?

Tags: nexus-4, mobile-network

I am planning to buy a Nexus 4 from US and want to use it in India. 
Should I expect any issues with this?
Is that phone compatible with all carriers in India?
Are there any power related problems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the phone is compatible with all Indian carriers. I personally use it on Vodafone.  
Side note: Why are you buying it from the US when it's available here? The $200 model is sold out you know.

Comment: Maybe because it's cheaper in the US?

Comment: Because here nexus 4 is more costlier than brought from US.
Here price: 26000
US: 249$= approx 16000

Answer (score 0):

There was an India-specific version released with a different Android build, including a different Radio. (Build JDQ39E).

I don't believe there are any hardware differences, and I have personally never been to India. If it doesn't work when you get it home, you may need to flash the Indian version's radio image with Fastboot.

[Link for the radio (and many other radios)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2087227).

Comment: Can you please tell me that what is that radio image?
And how come it affect over here(in india)?

Comment: I already specified the build number with the radio and gave a link. I don't know anything else about it, sorry.